# want to verify how use bcrypt

Tags: security, encryption, hash, bcrypt

It seems that understanding what bcrypt is all about not clear for some people and as well as for me since I still keep reading SOF users' questions. I got an example here about how to use bcrypt hashing:[How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

As I understand that bcrypt is one-way string, and if so that means I can use it for hashing only. There are some articles mention that bcrypt is also used for encrypting, which is none sense to me and that's because if I can encrypt a string that means I can decrypt it.

how the question is if bcrypt can be used for encryption, then how? can anyone give any example, please??

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) hashfunction/KDF is for hashing only.

[blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29), on which bcrypt is based is a block cipher i.e. it is used for encryption.

There is also an unrelated program called [bcrypt](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net), which uses blowfish based encryption.

Unfortunately many people use `bcrypt` and `blowfish` interchangeably, which leads to confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. so what was in the link above in my original post is hashing using bcrypt. And blowfish is a bcrypt-based function. ok, great to know. in this case if I want to encrypt information, I have to use blowfish to do this.

Comment: @Fxdigi It's the other way round. The `bcrypt` hash is based on `blowfish`. For encryption you could use blowfish, but I'd prefer AES.

Answer (score 1):

bcrypt() in php is a one way hashing function, so would not be suitable for two way encryption/decryption.

However there are packages availible called [bcrypt](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/) which is not a PHP function which is just an implementation of the blowfish cipher which allows two way (encryption and decryption).

So bcrypt can do decryption however bcrypt() cannot

Comment: Thanks John, great to know. I guess [phpass] has something related with bcrypt and some example(http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), but i was confused since many people use the same term for different uses. Thanks again for the info